# Hosting two websites in a same IIS server using two ports

Tags: url, redirect, iis, dns, reverse-proxy

I have an IIS server which is hosted one website using default port number `80` and it is bind to `mywebsite1.com:80`. It is able to view using its domain `mywebsite1.com` without any issue. Now I hosted another website using port no `70` and need to bind `mywebsite2.com` to it. But since DNS record not supporting to the port numbers, I am able to view my newly hosted website using the URL  `mywebsite2.com:70`. Is there any way to avoid putting port no there and access the website using its domain `mywebsite2.com` directly.

Windows Version : Windows Server 2016, 
IIS Version : 10.0.14393.0

Comment: You can just run `mywebsite2.com` also on port 80....

Comment: Thanks @Dusan, but I have tried to use the same ports, then it will replace my SSL certificates. I need to have separate SSL certificates for the 2 websites. Seems can't add two different SSL certificates by using single port.

Comment: Although I am not IIS expert, I am sure that it is possible

Comment: https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/host-different-ssls-on-one-ip-with-iis-8-sni/

Comment: "it will replace my SSL certificates"? Please learn what is SNI, and IIS 10 already supports that, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Dusan Bajic and @Lex Li for the guidance. I was able to solve this issue by ticking the **“Require Server Name Indication”** in IIS site bindings.

[image: edit site binding]

*Reference : https://www.sherweb.com/blog/cloud-server/host-different-ssls-on-one-ip-with-iis-8-sni/*

Then i set up the HTTP/HTTPS redirect in IIS and now everything working fine,
(https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https)